# How do I find out whenever a value changes in a certain column?

Tags: t-sql, query, automation

Need help if anyone can offer!

I currently have my select statement returning the TOP 1000 * results from a table. They are CC numbers that are currently active. I'd like to see how I can go about writing a query that could show me what has CC numbers have changed.

If something has changed, it will send a report to the listed people. If nothing, then it does nothing. It only actions once something has happened. We have an inhouse system that will do the automated part... I just need a select statement that will return what has changed. If I can get some help on this, it would be amazing!

Thank you!

Comment: please see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql and make a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

If you're not already logging changes yourself in your user defined tables, then you'll need to implement a feature that does so for your. Here is a list of features you can use to accomplish this:

1. [**Triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - Fire whenever data changes in a table, can implement logic similar to being in the context of a stored procedure.
2. [**Temporal Tables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) - System versioned copies of the user defined tables that track changes.
3. [**Change Tracking**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Automated tracking of changes for your user defined tables.
4. [**Change Data Capture**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Keeps track of **DML** changes to the specified user defined tables.
5. [**Audit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - Automatically tracks a multitude of actions at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what triggers do.
Please have a look at https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/ or https://www.sqlshack.com/triggers-in-sql-server/ or https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5909/sql-server-trigger-example/ you will find more information.

If you just need an update trigger it will be something like:

```
create trigger triggername on yourtable for update as begin yourcommands end;
```

Hope it helps.