# Would like to see what Credit Card Numbers have changed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data

Using the following SELECT Statement, I see all active drivers with a Credit Card Number :

```
SELECT top 1000 *
FROM cashcard
WHERE crd_status = 'A'
```

Based on that query, I get a table with a bunch of columns. The column I'm focused on is the first one titled `crd_cardnumber` which is a list of credit card numbers that are associated with people that are active in our database.

This is connected to our in-house database and we have an application that will run an automated query.

I just need to create a SELECT statement that will return **What has changed...** in the `crd_cardnumber` column when I run it.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE, some sample data (5-10 rows) as INSERT INTO, and desired output for this data.

Comment: Not sure asking for credit card numbers is appropriate

Comment: What is the reference point? If there is no old data, no flag, or any other data to use, it is not possible to decide if a card number changed.

Comment: do you have any last_updated_on column in your table? how do you track when it was changed?

Comment: Storing credit card information is a serious risk. Some of it you should not store, but anything you do store should be encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Directly *plagiarized* from my [answer on a similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/289387/150011):

If you're not already logging changes yourself in your user defined tables (either with a column to denote when a change occurs, at least, or by capturing the actual changes themselves), then you'll need to implement a feature that does so for your. Here is a list of features you can use to accomplish this:

1. [**Triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - Fire whenever data changes in a table, can implement logic similar to being in the context of a stored procedure.
2. [**Temporal Tables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) - System versioned copies of the user defined tables that track changes.
3. [**Change Tracking**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Automated tracking of changes for your user defined tables.
4. [**Change Data Capture**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Keeps track of DML changes to the specified user defined tables.
5. [**Audit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - Automatically tracks a multitude of actions at the server level.